# Stale Subscriber Trigger? Tests Only Pass When Trigger Body Modified Most Recently

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, failing-tests, platform-event

Getting started with Platform Events has been a bit of a rocky start for me. At least, getting any of the Unit Tests to pass consistently. The feature itself has worked every bit as well as I hoped, but there have been myriad issues with any sort of testing consistency. Now I think I've found the weirdest behavior yet, which I'll lay out below in more detail. **TL;DR** - If the trigger body is modified more recently than the service class, my tests pass. If the contrary is true, they fail.

Here are the basic steps which can be used to reproduce the issue:

1. Create a `Platform Event` object type named `Demo__e`.
2. Create an `Apex Class` to act as a service layer:

   ```
   public class DemoService
   {
       public static void doStuff(List<Demo__e> events)
       {
           List<Task> records = new List<Task>();
           for (Demo__e event : events)
               records.add(new Task(Subject=event.ReplayId));
           insert records;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create an `Apex Trigger` on this object:

   ```
   trigger Demo on Demo__e (after insert)
   {
       DemoService.doStuff(trigger.new);
   }
   ```
4. Create an `Apex Class` for Unit Tests:

   ```
   @IsTest
   class DemoTests
   {
       static testmethod void testSubscriberTrigger()
       {
           Test.startTest();
               EventBus.publish(new Demo__e());
           Test.stopTest();

           system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM Task], 'The trigger should fire');
       }
   }
   ```
5. Run `DemoTests`. It passes.
6. Save the `DemoService` class with no changes.
7. Run `DemoTests`. It fails.
8. Save the `Demo` trigger with no changes.
9. Run `DemoTests`. It passes.
10. Repeat 6-9 a few times as needed to confirm you have lost your mind.

Is anyone else able to reproduce this behavior? Or does anyone have an org where this behavior is not reproducible?

Comment: Found similar issues with push topic as well. Got to be related although I have not narrowed down the specific events that cause it. In my case the push topic is created by a managed package

Comment: Are DemoTests, DemoService, and Demo all the same API version?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yessir triple checked they are all 40.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this, and I've found the source. Modifying the class invalidates the trigger body, which causes the trigger not to fire, ultimately causing the assertion failure. You can apparently fix this condition by using metadata's [compileAndTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest.htm) to deploy all components at once, or using the *Compile all classes* function under Setup > Develop > Apex Classes. This is apparently a bug, since Salesforce is supposed to compile all invalid code bodies the first time they're used. For now, make sure you deploy all elements at the same time, write up a script to use compileAndTest, or manually recompile everything using the function in the UI. Also, log a bug with Support.

---

You'll want to watch [Peek Under the Hood of the New Apex Compiler](https://www.salesforce.com/video/303091/) regarding the Apex Code Compiler.

What happens during development is that when you deploy/modify a class, all classes and triggers dependent upon it are marked as invalid and purged from the code cache. Classes and triggers are recompiled on demand, such as when you create a new record, view a page, etc. However, unit tests appear to only use code that's already in the cache, so the trigger remains in an invalid state until it is recompiled later, thus it never executes.

Comment: Can you add any more depth or reference to why the trigger becomes invalid?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Added a link to a video, and a short explanation. It appears to be related more to just development cycles than anything. I'm actually pretty sure that salesforce might already have a bug logged for this, thinking about it. Just make sure you recompile and you should be okay.

Comment: Just getting back to this one, will have a watch of that video and see if it makes more sense.